# matplotlib: `tight_layout()` didn't work in PyQt widget

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt5

I've built a PyQt application to show three subplot using `gridspec`:

```
class Mesh(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, Max_i, Max_j, file='',
             mesh_string='', nkx=0, nky=0, factor=1.1, figsize=(12, 8),
             facecolor='none', dpi=100):

    self.figure = Figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi, facecolor=facecolor)


    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)

    ...
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 4)
    ax_main = self.figure.add_subplot(gs[:2, :])
    ax_dx = self.figure.add_subplot(gs[2, :2])
    ax_dy = self.figure.add_subplot(gs[2, 2:])
    gs.update(wspace=100)

    ax_dx.plot(Arr_x[: Max_i], Arr_dx, 'k-', lw=1.2)
    ax_dy.plot(Arr_y[: Max_j], Arr_dy, 'k-', lw=1.2)
    ax_dx.set_xlim(Arr_x[0], Arr_x[Max_i - 1])
    ax_dx.set_ylim(0, Arr_dx.max() * factor)
    ax_dy.set_xlim(Arr_y[0], Arr_y[Max_j - 1])
    ax_dy.set_ylim(0, Arr_dy.max() * factor)
    ax_dx.set_xlabel('x')
    ax_dx.set_ylabel('dx')
    ax_dy.set_xlabel('y')
    ax_dy.set_ylabel('dy')
    ...

    #set tight_layout here!
    gs.tight_layout(self.figure)
```

However, the labels of different axes still overlapping each other, nothing changed at all, it seems `tight_layout()` didn't work in `Qt` widget, so is there another way to arrange subplots in `Qt` widget?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subplots_adjust` to change the spacing between plots and the edges of the figure:

```
self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.9,
                            bottom=0.1,top=0.9,
                            hspace=0.2,wspace=0.2)
```

Where `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` adjust the width of the margins at the edge of the figure, and `hspace` and `wspace` change the vertical and horizontal spaces between plots, respectively.

So, it sounds like you need to increase your `hspace` and `wspace`. It might take some experimenting to find a good configuration for your figure.